# Put each word into new line

Tags: c, newline

need your help: I have a function which have to sort out only palindromes and function is doing her job very well, but then I have to put it to a file (one word into new line) it didn't put correctly.

Input:

```html
civic panda


level
hezo

aba        panda rotator
```

What I got from function if write printf("%s", outBuffer) (It's correctly):

```html
civiclevelabarotator
```

And here each word should be in the newline. How to do it?

Main:

```html
while (fgets(inBuffer, LENGTH, in_file) != NULL)
    {
        isPalindrome(inBuffer, outBuffer);
        fputs(outBuffer, out_file);
    }
```

Comment: This looks like homework and should probably be marked as such.

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic: the homework tag was removed years ago.  If that’s what you mean by “marked as such” then history is against you.  I’m not convinced any such tag is needed, or commentary in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`puts()` adds a new line by default. If using `fputs()` do

```
fputs("\n",filepointer);
```

Comment: If I write fputs("\n", out_file) - the new line appears before first word, and after each word appears TWO new lines

Comment: @Mellowas Question lacks enoough code to agree or disagree with you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607942/put-each-word-into-new-line#comment82174371_47607978)  Post enough code to replicate the problem